# Dropdown List Required Field Validator not working

Tags: asp.net

I have tried to insert the required field validator for dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DrpAccountDetails" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Auto" Selected="true">--- Select Account Details ---</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Acct1">John 123-45678-9</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqAccount" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Please Select Account Details"  
            ControlToValidate="DrpAccountDetails" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But I got this error upon running it

> WebForms UnobstructiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)

Anyone has any idea what does it mean? and how to solve it?

Comment: sounds like you didn't include jQuery in your page

Answer (score 1):

> [UnobtrusiveValidationMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440.aspx)
>   If this key value is set to "None" [default], the ASP.NET application will use the pre-4.5 behavior (JavaScript inline in the pages) for client-side validation logic. If this key value is set to "WebForms", ASP.NET uses HTML5 data-attributes and late bound JavaScript from an added script reference for client-side validation logic.

So add this in Web.Config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add this code line to your **Web.config** file :

```
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```